# Add standard line to graphs in facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have created a game to see how confidence correlates with knowledge. Here is a print out of the first few participants.
[image]

It would be easier to decipher the data (to see if participants are overconfident or not) if each of these graphs had a line showing what perfect calibration looked like (55% of questions right when one is 55% confident, 65% right when 65% confident, and so on). This would be a straight line, that shows that values that fall below it are a result of overconfidence. The problem is that I don't have data for such a line, it is more for analysis purposes. Does anyone know an easy way to plot a line that isn't included in the dataset, and how to do that to each graph in  a facet_wrap?

Here is the dataframe:

```
    df <- structure(list(Confidence = c("55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", 
                                            "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "65", "65", "65", "65", 
                                            "65", "65", "65", "65", "65", "65", "65", "65", "65", "75", "75", 
                                            "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", 
                                            "75", "75", "85", "85", "85", "85", "85", "85", "85", "85", "85", 
                                            "85", "85", "85", "85", "85", "95", "95", "95", "95", "95", "95", 
                                            "95", "95", "95", "95", "95", "95", "95", "95", "95"), 
    Type = c("Participants' Calibration",                                                                  "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration"), 
Participant = c("1", "3", "4", "2", " 24", " 27", " 32", " 34", 
                                                               " 35", " 36", " 6", "7", "6", "1", "3", "4", "2", " 24", " 27", 
                                                               " 32", " 34", " 35", " 36", " 6", "7", "6", "1", "3", "4", "5", 
                                                               " 10", " 11", " 24", " 27", " 32", " 34", " 35", " 36", " 6", 
                                                               "7", "6", "1", "3", "4", "5", "2", " 10", " 11", " 24", " 27", 
                                                               " 32", " 34", " 6", "7", "6", "3", "4", "5", "2", " 10", " 11", 
                                                               " 24", " 27", " 32", " 34", " 35", " 36", " 6", "7", "6"), 
    Accuracy = c(0.642857142857143, 
                                                                                                                                       0.5, 0.75, 0.583333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.65, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
                                                                                                                                       0.478260869565217, 0.555555555555556, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.545454545454545, 
                                                                                                                                       0.3125, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0.777777777777778, 0.2, 0.375, 
                                                                                                                                       0.333333333333333, 0.8, 0.625, 0.666666666666667, 0.555555555555556, 
                                                                                                                                       0.666666666666667, 0.857142857142857, 0.5, 0.5, 0.142857142857143, 
                                                                                                                                       0.142857142857143, 1, 0.8, 0.571428571428571, 1, 0.428571428571429, 
                                                                                                                                       0.5, 0.875, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 1, 0.333333333333333, 
                                                                                                                                       0.7, 0.615384615384615, 0.857142857142857, 0.615384615384615, 
                                                                                                                                       0.875, 1, 0.5, 0.916666666666667, 1, 0.6, 0.75, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
                                                                                                                                       0.866666666666667, 0.6, 0.5, 0.6, 0.96551724137931, 1, 1, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                                       0.91304347826087, 1, 1, 0.681818181818182, 0.8, 1), se = c(0.132894358488438, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.5, 0.163663417676994, 0.148647097502641, 0.0903876907577734, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.109424330980483, 0.188982236504614, 0.333333333333333, 0.106499554034051, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.175682092231577, 0, 0.114332390095006, 0.157459164324443, 0.119678388469542, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.188982236504614, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.146986183948033, 0.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.18298126367785, 0.333333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 0.18298126367785, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.333333333333333, 0.175682092231577, 0.333333333333333, 0.142857142857143, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.121267812518167, 0.288675134594813, 0.142857142857143, 0.142857142857143, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0, 0.2, 0.202030508910442, 0, 0.202030508910442, 0.5, 0.125, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.333333333333333, 0.288675134594813, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.152752523165195, 0.140441681411581, 0.142857142857143, 0.140441681411581, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.125, 0, 0.5, 0.0833333333333333, 0, 0.163299316185545, 0.25, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.0908513525158996, 0.112390297389803, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.121267812518167, 0.112390297389803, 0.0344827586206897, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0, 0.18298126367785, 0.0600738504093702, 0, 0, 0.101639453522718, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -70L), 
    groups = structure(list(Confidence = c("55", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "65", "75", "85", "95"), 
    Type = c("Participants' Calibration", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", "Participants' Calibration", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Participants' Calibration"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:13, 14:26, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   27:41, 42:55, 56:70), 
    ptype = integer(0), 
    class = c("vctrs_list_of",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
    row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
    class = c("tbl_df",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"), 
    .drop = TRUE), 
    class = c("grouped_df",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
    na.action = structure(c(`14` = 14L,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     `19` = 19L, `29` = 29L, `34` = 34L, `46` = 46L, `58` = 58L, `59` = 59L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         `63` = 63L, `79` = 79L), class = "omit"))
```

And the code for the graphs:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Confidence, Type, Participant) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Confidence, y= Accuracy, color = Type, group = Type)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Accuracy - se, ymax = Accuracy + se), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .2) + 
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
  labs(y= "YOU ARE RIGHT ___% OF THE TIME.", x = "WHEN YOU ARE ___ % CONFIDENT IN YOUR ANSWER...")+
  theme_minimal() + 
  facet_wrap(~Participant)+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 7))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to your plot `geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0)`.

This will only work if your x and y axes are both numeric and on the same scale. Apparently your x values are strings? Let's fix that:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Confidence = as.numeric(Confidence) / 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Confidence, y= Accuracy, color = Type, group = Type)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Accuracy - se, ymax = Accuracy + se), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .01) + 
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))+ 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))+ 
  labs(y= "YOU ARE RIGHT ___% OF THE TIME.", x = "WHEN YOU ARE ___ % CONFIDENT IN YOUR ANSWER...")+
  theme_minimal() + 
  facet_wrap(~Participant)+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 7),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0)
```

[image]